# Syntax error in delete statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to delete the record from my "student" table, the table has two column rollno and student name.

I am using a `PreparedStatement` but I am getting some error. I could not understand the error. The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

here is my code

```
    String query = "delete from student where rollno = ?";

    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

      pst.setInt(1, 7);
     pst.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: You forgot to share the most important part: How do you execute the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely you are calling the execute like this:

```
pst.executeUpdate(query);
```

This will execute the raw query, without the parameter you set before.

You want to execute the prepared query instead, so just use:

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```